# Embed and resize image in Excel maintaining aspect ratio

Tags: vba, image, resize, embed, aspect-ratio

I'm trying to write a VBA macro for Excel to embed and resize an image maintaining aspect ratio. I'd like to embed rather than link so Excel file can be shared between computers.

I have 2 pieces of code.

1st will embed an image (SaveWithDocument), position the image and change the height (but not maintain aspect ratio).

```
Sub Button7_Click()

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .ButtonName = "Submit"
        .Title = "Select an image file"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "JPG", "*.JPG"
        .Filters.Add "JPEG File Interchange Format", "*.JPEG"
        .Filters.Add "Graphics Interchange Format", "*.GIF"
        .Filters.Add "Portable Network Graphics", "*.PNG"
        .Filters.Add "Tag Image File Format", "*.TIFF"
        .Filters.Add "All Pictures", "*.*"

        If .Show = -1 Then

Set pic = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(.SelectedItems(1), _
        LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
        SaveWithDocument:=msoCTrue, _
        Left:=1050, _
        Top:=35, _
        Width:=-1, _
        Height:=150)

Else
            MsgBox ("No picture inserted")
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

2nd will link an image, poistion the image and change the height (maintaining aspect ration). This option will not embed image.

```
Sub Button7_Click()

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .ButtonName = "Submit"
        .Title = "Select an image file"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "JPG", "*.JPG"
        .Filters.Add "JPEG File Interchange Format", "*.JPEG"
        .Filters.Add "Graphics Interchange Format", "*.GIF"
        .Filters.Add "Portable Network Graphics", "*.PNG"
        .Filters.Add "Tag Image File Format", "*.TIFF"
        .Filters.Add "All Pictures", "*.*"

        If .Show = -1 Then

With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(.SelectedItems(1))
    .ShapeRange.lockaspectratio = msoTrue
    .Left = 1050
    .Top = 35
    .Height = 150
End With

Else
            MsgBox ("No picture inserted")
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Whilst both pieces of code work well separately, I am unable to combine them. I understand "SaveWithDocument" doesn't work with "Pictures.Insert" and "LockAspectRatio" doesn't work with "Shapes.AddPicture"?

Can anyone offer some guidance?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be solved now, and works well. Many thanks for the help.

```
Sub Button7_Click()

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .ButtonName = "Submit"
        .Title = "Select an image file"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "JPG", "*.JPG"
        .Filters.Add "JPEG File Interchange Format", "*.JPEG"
        .Filters.Add "Graphics Interchange Format", "*.GIF"
        .Filters.Add "Portable Network Graphics", "*.PNG"
        .Filters.Add "Tag Image File Format", "*.TIFF"
        .Filters.Add "All Pictures", "*.*"

        If .Show = -1 Then

        Dim pic As Shape
        Set pic = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(.SelectedItems(1), _
           LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
         SaveWithDocument:=msoCTrue, _
         Left:=1050, _
         Top:=35, _
         Width:=-1, _
         Height:=-1)
      pic.lockaspectratio = msoTrue
      pic.Height = 150

      Else
        MsgBox ("No picture inserted")
       End If

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do it in 2 steps I think it will work, i.e., insert the image in original size and set LockAspectRatio, then resize it.

```
Set pic = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(.SelectedItems(1), _
    LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
    SaveWithDocument:=msoCTrue, _
    Left:=1050, _
    Top:=35, _
    Width:=-1, _
    Height:=-1).LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
pic.Height = 150
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply Red. Unfortunately I get a Run-time error '13'. Type mismatch when I substitute in this code. Could this be because I am trying to address the Height value twice in different formats?